# Always Show Horizontal Scrollbar in webkit browsers (Specially Safari and iOS devices)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My first question on Stack Overflow. I have googled a lot to find this answer but nothing seems to work. I want a horizontal scrollbar for stack on iOS devices. the problem is, when I use -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; The scrollbar only appears while scrolling. Other techniques work, but they don't let the stack scroll smoothly AND I am unable to hold the scrollbar and move the stack. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

I have tried all the scenarios and tried all combinations of the CSS mentioned below.

```
    ::-webkit - scrollbar {
        display: block;
        height: 15 px;
    }
    .wrapper {
        padding - left: 92.5 px;
        padding - right: 92.5 px;
        padding - left: 0!important;
        display: -webkit - box;
        display: -ms - flexbox;
        display: flex;
        - webkit - overflow - scrolling: touch;
    }
    .owl - stage - outer {
        overflow: scroll;
        - webkit - overflow - scrolling: touch;
    }
    ::-webkit - scrollbar - track {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    ::-webkit - scrollbar - thumb {
        -webkit - border - radius: 10 px;
        border - radius: 10 px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
        - webkit - box - shadow: inset 0 0 6 px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    <div class="owl-stage-outer">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div>example</div>
            <div>example</div>
            <div>example</div>
            //all stacks in here
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding `overflow-x: scroll;` to a css selector for the element you wish to have the horizontal scrollbar on?

Comment: Yes, I have tried everything thats on internet :) lol.

Comment: I tried -webkit-appearance: none ; Border, border shadows, overflows everthing. The problem is if I dont use overflow-scrolling, the scrollbar appears but I cant hold it. If I use overflow-scrolling: touch, it only appears when scrolling

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried. Otherwise, you'll get more people just guessing. It would be even better if you could include a [mcve] showing the problem using Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in a page).

Comment: I have updated my post with the code snippets

Answer (score -1):

The answer is:

use **overflow-x:scroll;** (only because the end result is not what you wanted doesn't mean it doesn't work) or **build your own** from scratch (a div that get update on scroll --obviously not recommended for performance issues.)

Comment: Does not work ! As mentioned above, I have tried all possible combinations